# Can't import tensor flow

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have successfully installed tensorflow using pip. I have python 2.7.11. To double check when I do **pip show tensorflow**, It shows me that tensorflow 0.8.0 version is succesfully installed.

But to test the installation I did

```
$python
import tensorflow as tf
```

then i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

when I do  **$pip show tensorflow** I get this

```
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: tensorflow
Version: 0.8.0
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: http://tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
Installer: pip
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: six, protobuf, wheel, numpy
Classifiers:
Development Status :: 4 - Beta
Intended Audience :: Developers
Intended Audience :: Education
Intended Audience :: Science/Research
License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License
Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7
Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Mathematics
Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules
Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries
Entry-points:
[console_scripts]
tensorboard = tensorflow.tensorboard.tensorboard:main
```

Comment: What does `pip show tensorflow` actually print?  What about `python -c 'import sys; print (sys.path)`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that when yo call python interpreter version 2.7 is default?
try type in your shell

```
python -V
```

to verify which version is default. If it isn't 2.7, try type

```
python2.7 -c "import tensorflow as tf"
```

and see if you get any error